# Screenshot testing with dynamic data

Tags: selenium, single-page-application, webpage-screenshot, visual-testing

How do you make screenshots for comparison of the SPA that displays some changing data like dates and time?

I am thinking of some mock data, but that very complicates implementation, as the app has many services that have to be mocked and supported

Comment: Have you though about comparing some particular parts of the image? Also some tools allow you to ignore certain areas of image while comparing

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.